# Suitable map API for tracking

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, tracking, bing-maps, yahoo-maps

What is the most suitable map API for vehicle tracking and fleet management service?

FYI, from Google map terms of service-

> License restricted for- (c) dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar enterprise applications (the Google Maps APIs can be used to track assets (such as cars, buses or other vehicles) as long as the tracking application is made available to the public without charge. For example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public transit or other transportation status information. If your Maps API Implementation is deployed internally or you are charging for use of your Maps API Implementation, please contact the Google Maps API Premier sales team for more information);

I am not comfortable with this clause. Do I need to pay if I integrate google map in my tracking application where users are supposed to pay for the tracking data storage and service?

Answer (score 0):

This may interest you:

1. Microsoft Maps API:
   http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx
2. Yahoo Maps API:
   http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to pay if I integrate google map in my tracking application where users are supposed to pay for the tracking data storage and service?

Yes, that's what it says.

Contact Google and get a quote.  For another use we got a quote that was quite reasonable -- your use might be more expensive.

Comment: Well... the quote I have got is not suitable for my company. 23$/user/year. And total 2 million reverse geocoding only. We need more flexibility. So, we are looking for a free start to see the growth of our service and then want to decide to get a commercial service based on our need.

Comment: For our use $23/user/year would have been great -- hah.  My recollection was something like $1000/month (paid yearly).  Of course our use case was just "load google maps over SSL to avoid browser warnings" -- our use is otherwise within the terms of the free API.